# Package 'graphics' required. Put the line (animate) error

Tags: animate

I found the below code and I tried to reproduce it and I got the following error.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[preview,border={10pt 0pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{atom.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=myyellow] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt) node {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=myorange] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
    \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\orbit(#1,#2,#3){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,pre=moveto,pre length=#3,
  mark=at position {#2} with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (1 and 4);
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \pos in {0,0.08,0.16,...,0.96}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%%Nucleons
\neutron(0.4,0.4)
\proton(0.4,-0.4)
\neutron(-0.4,-0.4)
\neutron(0.4,0.4)
\proton(-0.4,-0.4)
\proton(0.4,0.4)
\proton(-0.4,-0.4)
\proton(0.4,-0.4)
\neutron(-0.4,0.4)
\neutron(-0.4,0.4)
\neutron(0.4,-0.4)
\proton(-0.4,0.4)
%%orbits
\orbit(0,-\pos,0cm)
\orbit(195,\pos,0cm)
\orbit(120,-\pos,0cm)
\orbit(65,\pos,0cm)
\orbit(270,\pos,0cm)
\orbit(330,-\pos,0cm)
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex atom}
%
% convert to GIF animation
\immediate\write18{convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 200 -alpha remove atom.pdf atom.gif}
%
% convert to PNG
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 200 -alpha on atom.pdf atom-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
%\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=<integer>]{<frame rate>}{<PDF filename without extension>}{<left blank>}{<left blank>}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{8}{atom}{}{}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Update: I did add the graphicx package to the main file, but now I'm still getting the Missing number error

```
       \documentclass[preview,border={10pt 0pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{filecontents*}{atom.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=myyellow] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt) node {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=myorange] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
    \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\orbit(#1,#2,#3){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,pre=moveto,pre length=#3,
  mark=at position {#2} with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (1 and 4);
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \pos in {0,0.08,0.16,...,0.96}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%%Nucleons
\neutron(0.4,0.4)
\proton(0.4,-0.4)
\neutron(-0.4,-0.4)
\neutron(0.4,0.4)
\proton(-0.4,-0.4)
\proton(0.4,0.4)
\proton(-0.4,-0.4)
\proton(0.4,-0.4)
\neutron(-0.4,0.4)
\neutron(-0.4,0.4)
\neutron(0.4,-0.4)
\proton(-0.4,0.4)
%%orbits
\orbit(0,-\pos,0cm)
\orbit(195,\pos,0cm)
\orbit(120,-\pos,0cm)
\orbit(65,\pos,0cm)
\orbit(270,\pos,0cm)
\orbit(330,-\pos,0cm)
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex atom}
%
% convert to GIF animation
\immediate\write18{convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 200 -alpha remove atom.pdf atom.gif}
%
% convert to PNG
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 200 -alpha on atom.pdf atom-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother
%

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
%\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=<integer>]{<frame rate>}{<PDF filename without extension>}{<left blank>}{<left blank>}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{8}{atom}{}{}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: and did you try what the message says? did you add \usepackage{graphicx}?

Comment: Yes I did and didn't work for me, note that the package is already there in the code

Comment: it is only in the atom.tex file, not in your main file.

Comment: Can you please explain further or is there a way to understand the how the code works. It seems to me that he's running two different .tex files at the same time

Comment: Yes, there are two files processed. The file `atom.tex` embedded in the main file by means of the `filecontents` environment is processed via shell-escape to produce the animation frames. The main file then  makes use of the `animate` package to produce an animated PDF. Here, the `graphicx` package is needed. Hence, put `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble of the main file and you are done.

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer since it seems to solve the problem and there are no follow-up comments so far.

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere? If yes, maybe link the source for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The original issue, the reported error about missing `graphicx` package, has been solved by OP in the meantime.

Nevertheless there are more problems with the code:

The `filecontents` package is obsolete, the environment of the same name is now provided as a kernel built-in.

The TikZ part does not compile in a current TeXLive 2022 set-up; the shading commands have to be changed into `\shade[ball color=...] ...` in order to compile.

The GIF ad PNG versions of the animation frames in `atom.pdf` are not used for producing the final PDF animation. The corresponding system calls, `\write18{...}`, can be safely removed.

The fourth animation frame has a different bounding box than the other frames because of the electrons that pass through the vertices of the ellipses. This makes the animation "jump" at this frame. To fix it, some code was added to determine the maximum extent of the bounding boxes over all animation frames which is finally written as a `\useasboundingbox` command into the `aux` file. On the second `latex` run, this command is inserted in every `tikzpicture` environment to ensure the same bounding box to be used in all frames.

In fact, there is no need to first create the animation frames in a separate PDF via `--shell-escape`. Instead, the animation frames can be typeset and animated at once by means of the `animateinline` environment.

Animated SVG version:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{animate,tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
    \shade[ball color=myyellow] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt) node {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
    \shade[ball color=myorange] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
    \shade[ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
    \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\orbit(#1,#2,#3){%
  \draw [
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,pre=moveto,pre length=#3,
  mark=at position {#2} with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (1 and 4);
}

% starting values for finding largest bounding box
\def\xmin{100000}
\def\ymin{100000}
\def\xmax{-100000}
\def\ymax{-100000}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,autoplay,loop]{8}
\multiframe{12}{rPos=0+0.08}{  
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
  %insert \useasboundingbox with max bbox coordinates
  \ifdefined\bboxmax\bboxmax\fi
  %%Nucleons
  \neutron(0.4,0.4)
  \proton(0.4,-0.4)
  \neutron(-0.4,-0.4)
  \neutron(0.4,0.4)
  \proton(-0.4,-0.4)
  \proton(0.4,0.4)
  \proton(-0.4,-0.4)
  \proton(0.4,-0.4)
  \neutron(-0.4,0.4)
  \neutron(-0.4,0.4)
  \neutron(0.4,-0.4)
  \proton(-0.4,0.4)
  %%orbits
  \orbit(0,-\rPos,0cm)
  \orbit(195,\rPos,0cm)
  \orbit(120,-\rPos,0cm)
  \orbit(65,\rPos,0cm)
  \orbit(270,\rPos,0cm)
  \orbit(330,-\rPos,0cm)
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% <determine max bbox> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west} \pgfgetlastxy{\llx}{\lly}
  \pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east} \pgfgetlastxy{\urx}{\ury}
  \xdef\xmin{\fpeval{\xmin<\llx ? \xmin : \llx}}
  \xdef\ymin{\fpeval{\ymin<\lly ? \ymin : \lly}}
  \xdef\xmax{\fpeval{\xmax>\urx ? \xmax : \urx}}
  \xdef\ymax{\fpeval{\ymax>\ury ? \ymax : \ury}}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% </determine max bbox> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}

%%%% <write max bbox command to aux file> %%%%
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\bboxmax{\string\useasboundingbox (\xmin pt,\ymin pt) rectangle (\xmax pt,\ymax pt);}}%
\makeatother
%%%% </write max bbox command to aux file> %%%%

\end{document}
```

For completeness, the fixed version with an embedded document for creating the animation frames in a separate file. Requires `--shell-escape`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{atom.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
    \shade[ball color=myyellow] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt) node {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
    \shade[ball color=myorange] ({rnd*#1},{rnd*#2}) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
    \shade[ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
    \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\orbit(#1,#2,#3){%
  \draw [
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,pre=moveto,pre length=#3,
  mark=at position {#2} with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (1 and 4);
}

% starting values for finding largest bounding box
\def\xmin{100000}
\def\ymin{100000}
\def\xmax{-100000}
\def\ymax{-100000}

\begin{document}

\foreach \pos in {0,0.08,0.16,...,0.96}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
  %insert \useasboundingbox with max bbox coordinates
  \ifdefined\bboxmax\bboxmax\fi
  %%Nucleons
  \neutron(0.4,0.4)
  \proton(0.4,-0.4)
  \neutron(-0.4,-0.4)
  \neutron(0.4,0.4)
  \proton(-0.4,-0.4)
  \proton(0.4,0.4)
  \proton(-0.4,-0.4)
  \proton(0.4,-0.4)
  \neutron(-0.4,0.4)
  \neutron(-0.4,0.4)
  \neutron(0.4,-0.4)
  \proton(-0.4,0.4)
  %%orbits
  \orbit(0,-\pos,0cm)
  \orbit(195,\pos,0cm)
  \orbit(120,-\pos,0cm)
  \orbit(65,\pos,0cm)
  \orbit(270,\pos,0cm)
  \orbit(330,-\pos,0cm)
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% <determine max bbox> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west} \pgfgetlastxy{\llx}{\lly}
  \pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east} \pgfgetlastxy{\urx}{\ury}
  \xdef\xmin{\fpeval{\xmin<\llx ? \xmin : \llx}}
  \xdef\ymin{\fpeval{\ymin<\lly ? \ymin : \lly}}
  \xdef\xmax{\fpeval{\xmax>\urx ? \xmax : \urx}}
  \xdef\ymax{\fpeval{\ymax>\ury ? \ymax : \ury}}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% </determine max bbox> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

%%%% <write bbox command to aux file> %%%%
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\bboxmax{\string\useasboundingbox (\xmin pt,\ymin pt) rectangle (\xmax pt,\ymax pt);}}%
\makeatother
%%%% </write box command to aux file> %%%%

\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

% process embedded file for animation frames --> atom.pdf
\immediate\write18{pdflatex atom}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=<integer>]{<frame rate>}{<PDF filename without extension>}{<left blank>}{<left blank>}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{8}{atom}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing tutorial, I mean answer :).